# Can I access the data I stored in Flask.g after redirect?

Tags: python, flask

As Flask doc stated: g is

> A namespace object that can store data during an application context. This is a good place to store resources during a request.

g is used to share data accross function in each request. Does a redirect() call start a new request or it will operate the redirected view function under the same request.

Comment: A redirect results in a new request.

Comment: Thank you. So besides using url parameter, is there any other way to pass data to the redirected view function?

Comment: Please refer to the linked question.